# What does //$FALL-THROUGH$ do in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

What does  `//$FALL-THROUGH$` comment mean in Eclipse? I did Google but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suppresses a warning telling you that there is no `break;` from that `case`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Eclipse 3.5 release news](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-part2.html). There it is shown (you have search for "fall"). It is meant for cases where you cannot use `@SuppressWarnings("fallthrough")`.